# Save to chrome.storage on Setting Page and Read from Content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I read in https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
that it is possible for a content script to read directly from the storage api.

I have a setting page where i allow the user to save credentials, and i want to access those credentials from the content script. for some reason when i "get" from the content-script i get empty values...

Also -
How can i debug and see the Storage data from Chrome Developer tools?

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({'username':undefined,'password':undefined}, function(items) {
    console.log(items.username)
    username = items.username;
    password = items.password;
    console.log(typeof(username))
});
```

Comment: You should show how you are saving and reading the values if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I Found that if i don't use the Dictionary  in the .get api it works.
For some reason(probably a bug) when using the dictionary interface from content-script it doesn't find the data.

From the setting page the .get with dictionary worked.

Comment: its not a bug. the dictionary way is only to provide default values. an object with property undefined means it does not have the property so basically you are passing and empty object to the api. pass null and it will work.